# SQL Server 2012 Pivot - Concatenate with aggregate

Tags: sql-server-2012, pivot

I currently have a table with data by month in rows and fields as columns

```
Region  Location  Year  Month  FY15 Overtime Wages
East    Philly    2015  11     100
East    Philly    2015  12     105
West    NYC       2015  11     87
West    NYC       2015  12     94
```

I need this to look like:

```
Region  Location  [OT Spend 2015-11]  [OT Spend 2015-12]  ...etc...
East    Philly      100                 105               ...etc...
West    NYC         87                  94                ...etc...
```

I tried this, but no matter what changes I make, it errors out constantly (not worth writing the errors):

```
SELECT
  PC
  , 'OT Spend '&Format(Year & '-' & [Month #],'yyyy-mm')
FROM
  (select
    PC
    , Year
    , [Month #]
    , [FY15 Overtime Wages]
from
    [OT Extract]) p
PIVOT
(
  Sum([FY15 Overtime Wages])
  FOR [FY15 Overtime Wages]
  IN ('OT Spend '&Format(Year & '-' & [Month #],'yyyy-mm'))
) piv;
```

Any ideas or simplicity because I have another pivot table to create that is exactly the same but a different column.

Comment: What are the errors?  You need to concatenate those values together inside of your subquery so they are available for the `IN()` portion of the `PIVOT`.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near 'OT Spend '.
-- Also, I have done this in Access with ease, but not good with this SQL Server format (reason was moved from access to sql server) so if you have specifics, I could really use them for understanding.  Thanks